# regex content Monit

Tags: regex, monit

Sorry all,
i plan to fetch alert for monit content based on apache log files but i think this regex is wrong as i thought this will be work like based in grep i use from shell

```
check file vhost with path /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
       if content = '.*"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 200.*' then alert
```

- does above regex is wrong ? as i plan to alert only the line contains that word
- is it possible in regex monit content to have multiple keyword regex like below for example i often use in grep

`grep -P '(?=.*urlpath.*)(?=.*200.*)(?=.*302.*)' logfile`

Hope you can advice me regarding above regex

Many thanks

Comment: What is the string you are string to catch?

Comment: for now a line in log file contains this exactly "POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 200 (in apache log there is a line contains that with the double quote as well)

Answer (score 0):

have you read/see this https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#FILE-CONTENT-TEST

Your grep sample will not work, but you can use simple POSIX regex (see man 7 regex in a Linux system).

```
check file vhost with path /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
  if content = '.*"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" (200|302).*' then alert
```

Based on you sample message line, this will send alerts for status code 200 and 302.
If message lines with a status code 200 and 302 occur in a check time interval, you will get one alert only. The log file used by Monit should contain the matching messages.

```
[2022-07-13T16:32:11MESZ] error    : 'vhost' content match:
"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 200

[2022-07-13T16:33:11MESZ] info     : 'vhost' content doesn't match
[2022-07-13T16:33:11MESZ] info     : 'vhost' content doesn't match
[2022-07-13T16:45:11MESZ] error    : 'vhost' content match:
"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 200

[2022-07-13T16:45:11MESZ] error    : 'vhost' content match:
"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 302

[2022-07-13T16:46:11MESZ] error    : 'vhost' content doesn't match
```

But the alert sent will contain both/all message lines.

Comment: Sorry, do you think my first regex above should work like below ?
`if content = '.*"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 200.*' then alert`

But somehow i dont get an alert when i use above rule though before as i compare it by ansible playbook i fetch manually

Comment: I use echo '"POST /urlpath/ HTTP/1.1" 200' >> other_vhosts_access.log to add the test data to the checked file and got alerts all the time. Are you able to check the log file used by Monit, please.

Comment: Check the "set alert" statements in the monitrc file used by Monit to see the right (event "content") or all alerts are send (see https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-alert-recipient).

Comment: many thanks, i'll check the server config for that will update the result to you guys

Comment: Try to start monit with "monit -I -vv" in the foreground to get some more information and to see how Monit handle the content.